# How can I use express router routes for dual use?

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a node app using express router and routes, for example I have a router that handles fetching company objects from the database, within the Company router the get method looks like this:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    models.Company.get(Number(id), function(err, entity) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Get error:", err);
        }
        console.log('Got entity:', entity);
        req.data = entity;
        next()
    });
});
```

Now if I am in another router, say the Reviews router and I want to get a company I would like to be able to call this route in order to grab that company, instead of having to duplicate code.

How do I do that?

Comment: Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778807/how-can-i-use-express-router-routes-for-dual-use/39778922#39778922) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to update them if they need any improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a named function, if you really want to use the same handler:

```
function yourHandler(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    models.Company.get(Number(id), function(err, entity) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Get error:", err);
        }
        console.log('Got entity:', entity);
        req.data = entity;
        next()
    });
}
router.get('/:id', yourHandler);
router2.get('/companies/:id', yourHandler);
```

Or you can abstract away only the actual database lookup, by making a function that takes a callback:

```
function getCompany(id, callback) {
    models.Company.get(Number(id), function(err, entity) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Get error:", err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Got entity:', entity);
            callback(null, entity);
        }
    });
}
```

or a function that returns a promise:

```
function getCompany(id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        models.Company.get(Number(id), function(err, entity) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Get error:", err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Got entity:', entity);
                resolve(entity);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The difference is that you use the callback-taking version like this:

```
getCompany(123, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // you have data
  }
});
```

and you use the promise-returning version like this:

```
getCompany(123)
.then(function (data) {      
  // you have data
})
.catch(function (err) {
  // handle error
});
```

The callback versions are easy to compose using the `async` module and the promise versions are easy to compose using the `bluebird` module or some other promise framework. See:

- http://caolan.github.io/async/
- http://bluebirdjs.com/

It's also worth mentioning that Bluebird is much faster than native ES6 promises, see [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331991/are-native-promises-still-slower-in-node-vs-libraries-such-as-bluebird/331992#331992)  for details.

Comment: The solution with promises would the best one in this case. Although you don't need libraries for promises anymore, they're part of ES6, so if the OP is using v4.x or higher, they don't need a library for that.

Comment: Debugging is greatly improved using Bluebird though.

Comment: @OmarAlqady Yes, that's why I used native ES6 promises in the examples and I only mention Bluebird at the end saying that "the promise versions are easy to **compose** using the `bluebird` module or some other promise framework". See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html to see methods that are [not available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Methods) in ES6. Also [Bluebird is much faster](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/331991/are-native-promises-still-slower-in-node-vs-libraries-such-as-bluebird/331992#331992).

Comment: I noticed you only used native promises in your example, and no methods that are not available with native promises, which is why I commented on this. Although to be honest, I didn't know there was such a performance difference between the two implementations. From your tests on the linked post, the native promises do seem to be getting slower, the only thing that improved slightly is memory usage. This is very strange and rather disturbing :) If I had enough reputation on programmers I would have upvoted your answer there :) :)